# How to click on the button if there is no ClassName and ID is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

try:
    driver.get("URL Link")
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_id("ess.myAccount.Label").click()
except:
    print("Requested page is not opening")

driver.close()
```

What are the other way to click that button
HTML Source--Primary Account

Comment: You can click by text on button.//button[text()='Text on button']

Comment: Tried this one,still no luck "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Primary Account']").click()"

Comment: Plz post the source code of parent also

Comment: By looking at html, //a[text()='Primary Account'] should work

Answer (score 1):

use below as cssSelector and click:

```
a#ess\\.homeAccount\\.Label[onclick$='return false;']
```

or

```
a#ess\\.homeAccount\\.Label[onclick$='return false;'][href$='#']
```

or

```
 a[id^='ess'][onclick$='return false;'][href$='#']
```

u can also use this

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("ess\\.myAccount\\.Label").click()
```

Comment: Hi, that id contains '.' so i am expecting it may treated as className if we go for cssSelector.

Comment: @paranth, let me know what happens.

Comment: in ur id , use \\. so that . is not treated as class like ess\\.myAccount\\.Label

Comment: Tried all 3 "driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[id^='ess'][onclick$='return false;'][href$='#']")",still no response

Comment: i have updated my code .. in all 3 one \\. was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If id does not work then you try with other locators by which we can point specific required element. By using provided HTML code you may try

xpath:

> //a[@id='ess.homeAccount.Label'] //if id does not works xpath by
>   using id may works
>
> //a[contains(text(),'Primary Account')]

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the parent element, which actually has the `onclick` event

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('BM').click()
```